# Cleaning Data Text FIle

Tags: text

I have a large text file. The following is an example of the data

```
3;N;X;01;A00;A00.-;A00;A00;Cholera;001;4-002;3-003;2-001;1-002
4;T;X;01;A00;A00.0;A00.0;A000;Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae;001;4-002;3-003;2-001;1-002
4;T;X;01;A00;A00.1;A00.1;A001;Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor;001;4-002;3-003;2-001;1-002
4;T;X;01;A00;A00.9;A00.9;A009;Cholera, unspecified;001;4-002;3-003;2-001;1-002
3;N;X;01;A00;A01.-;A01;A01;Typhoid and paratyphoid fevers;002;4-002;3-003;2-003;1-004
4;T;X;01;A00;A01.0;A01.0;A010;Typhoid fever;002;4-002;3-003;2-003;1-004
4;T;X;01;A00;A01.1;A01.1;A011;Paratyphoid fever A;002;4-002;3-003;2-003;1-004
4;T;X;01;A00;A01.2;A01.2;A012;Paratyphoid fever B;002;4-002;3-003;2-003;1-004
4;T;X;01;A00;A01.3;A01.3;A013;Paratyphoid fever C;002;4-002;3-003;2-003;1-004
4;T;X;01;A00;A01.4;A01.4;A014;Paratyphoid fever, unspecified;002;4-002;3-003;2-003;1-004
```

I am only after the middle words. For example in row 1 Cholera,

I don't really come from a programming background but could potentially use SAS or Excel.

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: To filter data automatically, you have to find a pattern, that could be used to extract the wanted informations.

Comment: Use [sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) to do multi-line selection.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to extract this middle row, then you can do it like this:

`awk -F';' '{print $9}' file`